# Service broker for SQL Server 2016. "is_activation_enabled" keeps turning off

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

Service broker seems to be working for us and processing most messages except that **is_activation_enabled** switches from 0 to 1 and back again throughout the day on it's own. We can find no explanation for this. Why does it do this? Does it mean something is wrong? **is_activation_enabled** needs to stay on (=1) because we have an activation_procedure. We observe this flag by running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.service_queues
```

Can someone explain what could be causing this?

Note: I am aware that a poison message can disable the queue. Please do not confuse my question with is_receive_enabled or one of the other flags. The only flag I am asking about is **is_activaton_enabled**.

I am able to see when the queue is actively processing messages by running this query `select * from sys.dm_broker_queue_monitors` but the concept of actively processing messages and ENABLING the processing of messages are different things.

Hoping a service broker expert is out there somewhere!

Our version of Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: From the book of "there are no stupid questions": do you include `WHERE [name] = <myqueue>` normally to verify you're looking at the same queue every time? With no `ORDER BY` the results of this query are technically nondeterministic.

Comment: There are only 2 queues. No order by or sorting is necessary. We are quite sure we’re looking at the right thing. Are you knowledgeable about service broker?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was an extended events session, but I don't see an appropriate event. However, I think a DDL trigger is what you're looking for. Consider the following:

```
create trigger tr_catch_queue_alter
on DATABASE
for alter_queue
AS
BEGIN
    select EVENTDATA();
END
```

The body of the trigger is *not* what you want; you'll want to shred the XML that it outputs and store it in a table somewhere. When I ran it just now on my local instance, I got:

```
<EVENT_INSTANCE>
  <EventType>ALTER_QUEUE</EventType>
  <PostTime>2018-09-12T20:17:22.497</PostTime>
  <SPID>54</SPID>
  <ServerName>«redacted»</ServerName>
  <LoginName>«redacted»</LoginName>
  <UserName>dbo</UserName>
  <DatabaseName>«redacted»</DatabaseName>
  <SchemaName>dbo</SchemaName>
  <ObjectName>«redacted»</ObjectName>
  <ObjectType>QUEUE</ObjectType>
  <TSQLCommand>
    <SetOptions ANSI_NULLS="ON" ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT="ON" ANSI_PADDING="ON" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="ON" ENCRYPTED="FALSE" />
    <CommandText>alter queue «redacted» with activation (status = on, execute as owner, procedure_name = dbo.«redacted»)
</CommandText>
  </TSQLCommand>
</EVENT_INSTANCE>
```

(obviously `«redacted»` is just stuff that was sensitive data for my specific environment; when you run it you'll get the actual details).

Note: this is only the first step. But from the above, you can see you get the following information about the `alter queue` statement:

- when
- from what host
- by whom
- the actual statement

So, even though it's a first step, I would argue it has the potential to be a fairly large one.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the process was stopping because it encountered poison messages. We solved this by adding more validation to the stored procedure responsible for building the message before adding it into the service broker queue.